# Umbraco: Get ImageCropper & File Upload via SurfaceController

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I'm still new to Umbraco 7 but I've found my way around Surface Controllers.

I have created a SurfaceController which you can see future below. But what I can't figure out is how to grab the URL from an Image Cropper and File Upload, I would normally do something like this: `@node.GetCropUrl("uploadImage, "thumbnail");`

But that doesn't work inside the controller. How do I achieve this? My end goal is to display the URL in a IMG tag when clicking on a category on this page:  `http://sp34k.dk/portfolio/vue/` in the description area.

CODE:

```
https://jsfiddle.net/odg3zamx/7/
```

Comment: `GetCropUrl` is an extension method of `IPublishedContent` so just add `using Umbraco.Web;` inside your sufrace controller and you should be able to call GetCropUrl.

Comment: It worked like a charm buddy, thank you! If you'd like you can post a comment with your reply so I can flag it as the answer. If someone is curious then I added using Umbraco.Web; and gItem.imgUrl = node.GetCropUrl("uploadImage", "featured");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GetCropUrl` is an extension method of `IPublishedContent` so just add `using Umbraco.Web;` inside your sufrace controller and you should be able to call it. Like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Umbraco.Web.Mvc;
using Umbraco.Web;  //you are missing this namespace

public class PortfolioSurfaceController : SurfaceController
{
    // GET: PortfolioSurface
    public ActionResult GetCategoryDetails(int id)
    {
        GalleryItem gItem = new GalleryItem();
        var node = Umbraco.TypedContent(id);
        gItem.imgUrl = node.GetCropUrl("uploadImage", "featured");

        return Json(gItem, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```